# Problema com vue-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js

Boa tarde,
fiz a instalação global do vue-cli
**npm install -g vue-cli**
Ao tentar iniciar um projeto com o comando **vue init webpack my-project**
o seguinte erro é apresentado

**vue-cli · tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EINVAL 0.0.12.56:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)**

Ao tentar rodar o comando **npm run vue -- list** o errro é apresentado:

> crud_vue@1.0.0 vue
>  /home/luan.freitas/Documentos/APIRest/vuejs_testes/crud_vue
>   vue "list"
>      vue-cli · tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect EINVAL 0.0.12.56:80 - Local (0.0.0.0:0)
>   npm ERR! Linux 4.6.7-300.fc24.x86_64
>   npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "vue" "--" "list"
>   npm ERR! node v4.5.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! crud_vue@1.0.0 vue: `vue "list"`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the crud_vue@1.0.0 vue script 'vue "list"'.
>   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the crud_vue package,
>   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   npm ERR!     vue "list"
>   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   npm ERR!     npm bugs crud_vue
>   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR!     npm owner ls crud_vue
>   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /home/luan.freitas/Documentos/APIRest/vuejs_testes/crud_vue/npm-debug.log

Estou usando o fedora 24, node 4.5.0 e npm 2.15.9.

**Rodando o comando com `sudo`** a execução foi mais demorada, e a saída foi a seguinte.

```
vue-cli · connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.116:443

npm ERR! Linux 4.6.7-300.fc24.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "run" "vue" "--" "list"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! crud_vue@1.0.0 vue: `vue "list"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Qualquer ajuda já é bem vinda, kkkkk

Answer (score 4):

Como você instalou ele de modo global, não se utiliza o NPM pra rodar, para ver a lista de templates é só executar o comando:
`vue list` (obs, sem o `--`, pois é um comando, não opção).

E para executar o projeto você deve usar o comando:
`npm run dev` (para Webpack)

(caraca, agora que vi que a pergunta é de 8/2016 o.O)